# WebStorm - Dart import errors

Tags: dart, import, webstorm

I'm new to DART, so I was looking for some program to test and I found a little space invaders game. I have import the project in WebStorm, but there's an error with the import, and I don't understand where does the error comes from:

[image]

Are there any missing libraries? I did download the dart-sdk and linked it when I installed WebStorm, but I didn't provide any link for Dartium, is that what causes the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very old syntax (+2 years)

Use instead

```
import 'dart:html';
```

Comment: Thank you ! Is it the same about #source ? It is an old syntax and not used anymore ? If so, what are we using instead ?

Comment: No idea what `#source` was for. Could be `part`/`part of`. I suggest to search for more up-to-date documentation or tutorials at http://dartlang.org